# H.264 decoding failing to parse unusual frame headers

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, h.264, decoding

I'm reading an H.264 stream from a camera on a raspberry pi. I'm trying to pass this to [Broadway](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway) via websockets to render in a web page.

The stream contains NAL units, and I'm chunking it on the `[0,0,0,1]` start prefix code, to send and then decode NAL units individually. I think that's working fine, but Broadway can't decode the result I end up with.

Digging into [the parsing code I've based this on](https://github.com/131/h264-live-player/blob/master/vendor/dist/http-live-player.js#L4400-L4419) though, it seems to be expecting the 5th byte (straight after the start prefix code) to be either:

- 0x65 - an I frame
- 0x41 - a P frame
- 0x67 - an SPS frame
- 0x68 - a PPS frame

I've seen a lot of mention of these elsewhere too. All the units I have coming through though seem to start with (in order):

- 0x27 0x64 (1st unit)
- 0x28 0xEE (2nd unit)
- 0x25 0x88 (3rd unit, then intermittently later on)
- 0x21 0x9A (every single other unit in the stream)

What do these headers mean in an H.264 stream? Do they suggest something about what I need to do to match Broadway's expectations?

(If the full code would be useful to understand this better, see https://github.com/pimterry/pi-cam/tree/d801de9b)

Comment: read about the first byte of NALU [here](http://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a red herring: the actual issue for me here was that some existing frame dropping logic meant that I wasn't passing Broadway the first few frames in the stream, and it was failing to render. Replaying the SPS and PPS frames for all new connections and making sure they're never dropped has fixed the issue nicely.

I also did work out what these bytes are though, which helped, and may be useful for others for reference:

```
Hex    Binary     NAL type  Meaning
0x65 = 11 00101 = type 5    Coded slice of an IDR picture (I-frame)
0x41 = 10 00001 = type 1    Coded slice of a non-IDR picture (P-frame)

0x27 = 01 00111 = type 7    Sequence parameter set (B-frame)
0x28 = 01 01000 = type 8    Picture parameter set (B-frame)
0x25 = 01 00101 = type 5    Coded slice of an IDR picture (B-frame)
0x21 = 01 00001 = type 1    Coded slice of a non-IDR picture (B-frame)
```

Special thanks to [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) though - the NAL units article [here] and the [nal_ref_idc](http://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/breif-description-of-nal_ref_idc-value-in-h-246-nalu/) article made working this out much easier.